# What is the best way for my Dapp users to not pay gas fees?

Tags: ether, gas, dapps

I'm building a React/NodeJS Dapp for people who just have an email address and nothing more (no Ethereum address (and so no gas), no MetaMask, no Eth Wallets, etc..)

An address is created during the registration step, but gas is needed for that x)

I'm thinking about those two options:

- The user could set the gasPrice to 0. 
  Although this transaction would most likely not be picked up by the miners, the Dapp provider could mine all transaction going to his address.
- Stringify and store transactions data got with web3 getData() method and run them later with the Admin Eth Wallet address.

I can't see other ways.

If you guys have ideas, please share.

Comment: If your users don´t need an address and you don´t want to pay for gas, maybe you should not use Ethereum. The advantage of a blockchain solution like Ethereu is a decentralized ledger. Rethink about your solution or think about a private blockchain.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be useful https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38517/18932

Answer (score 1):

> The user could set the gasPrice to 0. Although this transaction would
>   most likely not be picked up by the miners, the Dapp provider could
>   mine all transaction going to his address.

This is an interesting question. 
 While we are still in PoW, the scenario you've described sounds possible. 
 I've made some [calculations](https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator):

- It will take you an average of **800 days** to find 1 Block if you are
  mining on a rig with one GTX 1080 Ti at 30MH/s .

*Information given above is only for example. It can vary.*

---

> the Dapp provider could mine all transaction going to his address

It seems like you should estimate the load on your service and make some math. In conclusion you should decide if it is worthy to have such provider, working for 0$ profit or just to pay all these tx fees by yourself.

Comment: 12.57 days does not seem right. The calculator you linked to gives over 800 days to find a block at 30MH/s (which is, I'm assuming is in the right ballpark for a 1080 Ti, give or take a factor of 2).

Comment: @lungj you are right, I had used incorrect hashrate table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to have Ethereum addresses and Ether, all you have to do is make your javascript (or whatever language you're using) to call transactions from a "server" contract (with your Ether).

That's what I did for an application that used the blockchain in background, it was invisible to the users, all they knew was that it was "secured with blockchain".

So you'll need an address that you periodically refill with Ether, but be careful, if malicious users attack you site or DDoS you they can potentially send way too many transactions and cost you a lot of Ether.

Answer (score 0):

"An address is created during the registration step, but gas is needed for that x)"

What are you doing with the address? It it's just creation, you don't need to generate a transaction and therefore you don't need gas. You'll only need that if you're changing the state of the blockchain.