# Gas payment of the mint of ERC20 Token

Tags: transactions, erc-20, gas

I have the follow use case:
There is an off-chain service, like a game, which will generate/mint new ERC20 tokens when some requirements are met by end-users. Since the users will get profit (in terms of ERC20 tokens), I do not want to pay the transaction fee of calling the `mint` function in the ERC20 contract.

`Question`: How can I make users pay the transaction fee of `mint` while under the control of my off-chain service (e.g. not violating the rule of minting new tokens)?

I know usually, this gas-paid-by-someone-else use case is often something like: the user do not need to pay the transaction fee, while a third-party will pay the fee. And there are a lot of mature libraries can do this, like openzeppelin GSN. But in my case, this is different.

I found a related question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38479/how-to-make-someone-else-pay-for-gas) talking about the general solution to such problems. But I prefer not to implement too many things by myself, since there may be security issues. Are there any libraries that can help me achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perform the minting as part of one of the user's transactions (for example, when that user withdraws his/her tokens).

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for comment. But if I do this way, how can I make sure if the user is withdrawing the tokens without violating any regulations?

Comment: Go over each regulation, and make sure that it is not violated.

Comment: But the thing is: the regulations are not in smart contracts. They are coded in off-chain service. I think I should let users directly call the smart contract functions.

Comment: So add them to the smart contract and then verify them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But in my case, I cannot do this.

Comment: Of course you can.